# The browser support for excel add-in is on my own site or the excel online app?

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-addins

The [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-overview) says

> An Excel add-in allows you to extend Excel application functionality across multiple platforms including Windows, Mac, iPad, and in a **browser**

Does *browser* mean my own website/web app or the online excel app that Microsoft has at https://office.live.com? I have been through the documentation, but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the web The Excel JavaScript addins interact with Excel Online which runs in a browser.

Comment: A reference would be appreciated.

Comment: The second sentence says "Use Excel add-ins within a workbook to:"  Excel JS Addins need to run alongside an Excel workbook - if there is no Excel workbook they will not work. The JS Addins do not contain Excel functionality - they use the JS Excel API to communicate with an instance of Excel.

Comment: The term *Cross Platform* is misleading then.

Comment: A bit misleading, but the JS API is is a lot more cross-platform than the XLL API or the COM-Interop API, which are both Windows only, or the VBA-COM API which is Windows and Mac.

Comment: XLL just took me on a nostalgic trip... We've come a long way. A decade ago we wouldn't have expected cross platform to mean what it means today... 